# transact to cforig.bunpaivotex errored: VM error: invalid opcode. invalid opcode The execution might have thrown

Tags: solidity, remix

solidity 0.6.0 on Remix IDE

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

// Defines a new type with two fields.
// Declaring a struct outside of a contract allows
// it to be shared by multiple contracts.
// Here, this is not really needed.



struct Funder {

    address addr;    
    uint amount;
    uint distnum;
    uint rank;
}


contract cforig {

    // Structs can also be defined inside contracts, which makes them
    // visible only there and in derived contracts.
    struct Campaign {
        address payable beneficiary;
        uint fundingGoal;
        uint numFunders;
        uint numMemories;
        uint amount;
        uint votex;
        mapping (uint => Funder) funders;
        mapping (uint =>Omoide) Omoides;
    }
    
    uint numCampaigns;
    mapping (uint => Campaign) campaigns;

    function newCampaign(address payable beneficiary, uint goal) public returns (uint campaignID) {
        campaignID = numCampaigns++; // campaignID is return variable
        // We cannot use "campaigns[campaignID] = Campaign(beneficiary, goal, 0, 0)"
        // because the right hand side creates a memory-struct "Campaign" that contains a mapping.
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        c.beneficiary = beneficiary;
        c.fundingGoal = goal;
        c.votex=10000;
    }

    function contribute(uint campaignID) public payable {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        // Creates a new temporary memory struct, initialised with the given values
        // and copies it over to storage.
        // Note that you can also use Funder(msg.sender, msg.value) to initialise.
        
        c.funders[c.numFunders++] = Funder({addr: msg.sender, amount: msg.value, distnum:0, rank:0});
        c.amount += msg.value;
        
        bunpaivotex(campaignID);
        //Distribute votex for campaigns with new contributorsenter code here
        

    }


    function checkGoalReached(uint campaignID) public returns (bool reached) {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        if (c.amount < c.fundingGoal)
            return false;
        uint amount = c.amount;
        c.amount = 0;
        c.beneficiary.transfer(amount);
        return true;
    }
    
   
    
    function bunpaivotex(uint campaignID) public  {
        Campaign storage c = campaigns[campaignID];
        
       // for (uint i=0;i<c.numFunders;i++){
           // c.funders[i].distnum=(c.votex/c.amount)*c.funders[i].amount;
        //votex を分配、投票などに使用
        uint amount=c.amount;
        uint votex=c.votex;
        uint funamount=c.funders[0].amount;
        c.funders[0].distnum=(votex/amount)*funamount;
       // }       
    }
```

Thank you for all your help.

The contract "bunpanvotex" does not work with the above error.
"newcampaign" creates a new "campaign" and "contributes" money to the "campaign". bunpaivotex" passes a "votex" token to all the users who have sent money to the "votex" token, according to the number of participants "numFunders".

At first I thought I was using a non-existent argument in the for function, so I removed the for function using "numFunders" and put the necessary arguments for the token calculation in another function, "ex.amount", but it did not work. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check `c.amount` to make sure it's not zero. Because `campaigns` is a mapping, any initialized campaign will have all values being zero. `c.amount` being zero will lead to division by zero exception in `votex/amount` which revert tx and throws an invalid opcode after Solidity 4.0.

Comment: I was using "checkReached" to check, but then I set "c.amount" to 0.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that you fixed it, if it solved your problem please mark it as the answer to close this question @NIS_TAK